# Pandas - split column after the last instance of a delimiter only where there is 2 numeric following the delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to split a column in a pandas DataFrame following the last instance of a delimiter in this case: `-`, and only where the value after the delimiter is two numeric values.

An snippet of the DataFrame `df` is seen below.

```
full_code   

101-453-11                         
101-000-abc                          
202-abc-16                         
202-n12-n2                         
302-abc-xyz                          
302-qwe-11           
303-asd-12
```

I am hoping to achieve the follwoing output.

```
full_code     after_delimter

101-453       11                          
101-000-abc   nan                       
202-abc       16                     
202-n12-n2    nan                     
302-abc-xyz   nan                       
302-qwe       11       
303-asd       12
```

Any assistance anyone could provide would be greatly apprecaited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.assign(after_delimiter=
               df['full_code'].str.split('-')
               .apply(lambda x: x[-1] if len(x[-1]) == 2 and x[-1].isnumeric() else 'nan'))
mask = df['after_delimiter'].ne('nan')
df.loc[mask, 'full_code'] = df.loc[mask, 'full_code'].str[:-3]
>>> df
     full_code after_delimiter
0      101-453              11
1  101-000-abc             nan
2      202-abc              16
3   202-n12-n2             nan
4  302-abc-xyz             nan
5      302-qwe              11
6      303-asd              12
```

Note that the returned values are still strings, e.g. '11'. It is not clear what your expected data type should be, especially when you mix integers with NaN values.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer!

Comment: Hi Alexander, is there a way to also remove the values with two numeric values after the delimiter from the `full_code` column, similar to what is seen in the output DataFrame in the question? Thanks again

Comment: Thanks very much, clever use of `.ne`, I never would have thought of that